# What is the equivalent of cin.ignore() in Java?

Tags: java

I am a new learner of Java language and for the past two years I have been working with C++. I am gonna need something equivalent to `cin.ignore()` in Java.

Comment: Can you add what it is you need it to do in Java for those not familiar with that method?

Comment: I am working on a Dictionary and there is a check I need to ensure.
Well the input gets passed over it every time. No idea why!

Comment: In that case, I suggest you read all the input and debug your program to see why it is reading what it is doing.  Trying to hide a problem you don't understand has a habit being a disaster.

Comment: okay thank you Peter!
Well I was debugging my program. Its particularly an issue with String input using Scanner class.
No idea why it doesn't check "yes" or "no" input?

Comment: Oh! just find out I wasn't using .equals method. :)

Comment: Are you reading "yes" and "no" and using == to compare Strings, because that won't do what you think in Java.  You need to use `str.equals("yes")` to find out if two strings have the same contents.

Comment: That's because `String s` is a *reference* in Java.  Not the object.  When you use `==` to are asking if these are references to the same object, `equals` checks if the contents are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

In java equivalent of  `cin.ignore()` is `InputStream.skip()`. You can refer to [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Java you would read the text and remove the bits you don't want. e.g. instead of doing this.

```
first = std::cin.get();     // get one character
std::cin.ignore(256,' ');   // ignore until space

last = std::cin.get();      // get one character

std::cout << "Your initials are " << first << last << '\n';
```

you would do

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String first = in.next(), last = in.next();

System.out.println("Your initials are " + first.charAt(0)+last.charAt(0)+"\n");
```