# Error using InputStream.skip()

Tags: java, inputstream

I am looking for something similar to C++'s `cin.ignore()` function.

I am new to JAVA and I trying something like this

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in) ;   
int num1, num2 ; 

System.out.print("\n Enter the two numbers : " +
                 "\n number 1 : ") ;    
num1 = user_input.nextInt() ; 

System.out.print("\n Number 2 : ") ; 
num2 = user_input.nextInt() ;
```

After this line when I am trying to take a `String` input from the user like this

```
String choice; 
choice = user_input.nextLine() ;
```

It just ignores it continues to the next line.

I tried using `InputStream.skip(long) ;` just before taking the `String` input from the user.  I read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956306/what-is-the-equivalent-of-cin-ignore-in-java) that is equivalent to C++'s `cin.ignore()`

What is the mistake that I am making?

Oh I included this too `import java.io.InputStream;`

EDIT : I was asking for whether I could use `InputStream.skip()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > "It just ignores it continues to the next line."

When you say `num2 = user_input.nextInt() ;` You press the return (enter) key at the end as well which doesn't get read along with num2 and hence when you say `choice = user_input.nextLine();` it (return key) gets consumed with this method call and hence you see that it ignored your method call to read a line.

You could resolve this in two ways:

- You could read whole line and convert into integer while reading num2 like

  ```
  num2 = Integer.parseInt(user_input.nextLine());
  ```
- Or just to consume return key press, you could add additional call of readline like:

  ```
  user_input.nextLine();//consume enter key press
  choice = user_input.nextLine();
  ```